# Back button missing in new flagging menu

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, user-interface, flags

As you probably now there is an [improved flagging system](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/improved-flagging/).

When you flag as:

> it doesn't belong here

It shows you:

[image: The 'This question does not belong here' menu]

From which you can't go back to the original flagging menu.

I think it would be a good usability idea to put a link back to the flag menu there since you may want to see all your options before flagging in a certain way.

What do you think about this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Yi Jiang thanks for the edit, completely missed that tag!

Answer (score 6):

Great idea - this will be pushed in tonight's deployment.

The area on the lower left of the dialog now says "back" instead of "cancel".

Comment: The fact that you listen, makes me a proud member of this community. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There's still a minor issue with the flag dialog, [detailed in a related question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77957/the-new-fancier-flag-dialog-doesnt-allow-full-backtracking) that was mistakenly closed as a duplicate of this one. I think it can be resolved by making a few minor changes, though.

In the minified code, in the success handler `c(A, x, y)` for the AJAX call to get the close dialog after selecting the "it doesn't belong here" flag option, a click handler is assigned to the radio button that does not have `name="existing-close"`. This handler calls `g(E)`, which is responsible for turning the back/cancel link into a back link.

When it does this, it assigns another handler `e()` to the link which reverts those changes. Unfortunately `e()` turns the link into a cancel link, regardless of what it was before. Based on the code, it's possible that this is intentional, but it'd be nice if it could be changed given that the flag dialog seems to work fine either way.

So, what to do about it? One approach might be to save the original link instead of recycling it, e.g.:

```js
var g = function (y) {
    // ...
    x.addClass("popup-active-pane").show();

    var c = y.closest("div.popup").find(".popup-actions-cancel");

    // Save the original link with handlers, and insert a clone in its place
    // No need for unbind on the clone since we cloned without events
    c.before(c.clone().html("back").click(function () {
        e(c);
    })).detach();

    window["pane" + w]();

    return true;
};
```

coupled with the following changes in `e()`:

```js
var e = function (c) {
    $(".popup-subpane").removeClass("popup-active-pane").hide();
    $("#pane-main").addClass("popup-active-pane")
        .show().find("input[type=radio]:checked").removeAttr("checked")
        .end().find("li.action-selected").removeClass("action-selected");
    $(".popup").find(".popup-submit").disable();

    // Check if we have a link to reuse (should be always)
    if (c) {
        $(this).before(c).remove();
    } else {
        $(this).html("cancel").unbind("click").click(function () {
            $(".popup").fadeOutAndRemove()
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I just noticed this bug where the `back` button changes to the `cancel` button. Annoying to see that after 1 year this still isn't fixed. Your linked question shouldn't have been closed as it details a bug in the feature which was implemented due to the question in this thread. Too bad it was seen as a duplicate. Can't your question be reopened?