# The new, fancier flag dialog doesn't allow full backtracking

Tags: bug, user-interface, flag-dialog, close-dialog

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Back button missing in new flagging menu](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74956/back-button-missing-in-new-flagging-menu)

The [improved flagging dialog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/improved-flagging/) is fancy and shiny and nice, no question about it, but it contains a small navigation problem. More than once now, I've gone to flag a question on a site I don't have 3k on, and been unable to get back to "needs moderator attention — other" from the "exact duplicate" screen.

For example, say I come across a question and decide that it needs a duplicate flag, and click through "it doesn't belong here" to get "exact duplicate." At this point, I think "well, a description *could* be helpful" and hit "back" to return to the "it doesn't belong here" window.

At this point, I want to go back one more level, to the flagging main menu. Instead of the "back" link that was there originally, now there's a "cancel" link instead. When I click "cancel," the entire flag dialog disappears.

Here's a before and after image of clicking the "exact duplicate" radio button, the "After" scenario resulting from clicking "back" on the "exact duplicate" screen:

[image: Before and After illustration of link change]

I'm guessing this behavior is because the code for the link was copied from the old close dialog, where that window *was* the main menu, but it's annoying in this new situation.

Comment: Hm... this seems to be a duplicate of [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74956/back-button-missing-in-new-flagging-menu), about the inability to back away after "it doesn't belong here"?

Comment: @GraceNote This is more like the fix deployed for that question "undoes" itself if you go yet one more level deeper. I thought that was enough to make this report distinct, but I'm not the one with close votes anyway, heh.

Comment: @Tim It took me a few tries to finally observe this. The difference could be highlighted a little better.

Comment: @GraceNote I suggested an edit that might clarify the issue, hopefully Popular Demand doesn't mind me having chewed up his post too much.

Comment: As an aside, I suspect (without looking at the code) that the underlying problem is that the [fix here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74956/back-button-missing-in-new-flagging-menu/75278#75278) swaps the "back" for "cancel" after you click it once, so the click on the "exact duplicate" screen causes the swap prematurely.

Comment: @Tim, I happened to see it in my queue, and was going to approve it, but someone else approved it first.

Comment: @Jeff grr, this isn't a dupe :P

Comment: For what it's worth, I finally got around to [suggesting a fix for this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74956/back-button-missing-in-new-flagging-menu/97289#97289).